# Does scale/lime buildup in water heater cause inefficiency leading to more power use?

Tags: water-heater

I bought an apartment 6 years ago where hard water is a problem, and causes a buildup of lime/scale on heating element in the electric water heater. I didn't really know about this, and never cleaned it. I haven't noticed any problems.

I've been told it's recommended to service (remove the buildup) every 1-1.5 years. But that costs almost $100 every time - and a new water heater costs only $350. So financially that doesn't make much sense... (I have already saved enough to buy a new one by not paying for service)

So I'm thinking to just let it go until it stops working and rather just replace it with a new.

The main concern is of course electricity use. But I'm not sure I understand exactly why it would use more electricity because of the buildup. The element simply makes heat, and that same heat makes contact with the water eventually regardless of the scale buildup, doesn't it? If there is any loss, it can't be very large, can it?

Should point out it's located in a shed outdoors, so leaks won't cause any issues.

Comment: Also, I tried to change it to ask a more objective question as I it could be read as somewhat opinion-based, especially the title.

Comment: where do you live that you can get a new HWH for $350?

Comment: How much does actually having the new HWH installed cost?

Comment: Building ownership isn't relevant here. This is essentially a physics question.

Comment: Maintenance/replacement is on the landlord if it's a rental.

Answer (score 1):

The build up will act like insulation on the heaters.

The heat will go into the water but will take much longer, so if new it takes 5 minutes, with build up it will take 15 or 20 minutes to do the same heating, increasing the cost of electricity used.

You will save some heating cost due to the fact the scale will fill up some the tank so there will be less water to heat.

Can save some money by draining the tank a little bit every few months and see what comes out.  This should start when a tank is new.

For a six year tank will probably need a complete drain.  Turn off the power to the tank first.  Close the cold water inlet and open a hot water faucet somewhere to let air in.  The drain valve might need cleaning or replacing so be prepared for that.

Comment: But I don't understand why slower heating, means (noticeable) more energy used. For a water heater, the speed of the heating is of course irrelevant for normal use.
500w on for 10 minutes should generate the same amount of heat in the end, even if it first heats up the scale instead of the water? The heat in the scale will transfer to the water?

Comment: @JamesT  The first ten minutes spend heating scale only is ten minutes wasted.  The scale also prevents all the heat from reaching the water as fast.  It is like dumping a gallon of gas on the ground every time you fill up your car, your goes the same distance per tank, but you spend more money on gas.

Comment: I disagree. The laws of physics contradict this. The scale displaces water that would've needed to be heated anyway, starting from the same temperature. Even if heat transfer is slower through the scale, the same heat quantity would ultimately be produced and transferred. Local temperatures would be slightly different.

Comment: "*It is like dumping a gallon of gas on the ground ...*" Bad analogy, I think. All of the heat will go into the water. What does change is the thermal resistance between the heater and the water so the element will run at a higher temperature. This in turn may degrade the heater more quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Electric resistance heating is 100% efficient - with or without scale on the heating elements. The scale is IN the water being heated, so all heat that goes to the scale goes to the water.

Heavy scale buildup MAY cause the heating elements to degrade faster, as they may get hotter than they would if in *direct* contact with the water, and that might accellerate their aging and eventual failure.

That is, in fact, not that big of a deal - heating elements in electric water heaters are replaceable, inexpensively, and you can even spend a few dollars more on "low-density" elements that are longer (typically folded back on themselves, so they fit in the same space) and don't get as hot for the same wattage, (since there's roughly twice as much surface area) for the next set.

Eventually the tank rots out, and THEN you need a new water heater. For **that**, pay attention to the condition of your **anode rod**, and replace it as needed, to prolong tank life.

You could also install a **water softener**, either just on the cold water feeding the water heater, or the whole house, to reduce mineral build-up.

With an outside shed location for the heater, careful insulation of the pipes, and additional insulation of the heater would be places to look for **energy** savings.

Answer (score 0):

Scale buildup acts as insulation so the heat has more trouble spreading through the entire tank. Instead heat stays around the heating element, so the thermostat which is very close cuts it off. Then the heat spreads in the tank, and the thermostat turns it on again. Total energy use will be the same, but heating a full tank of cold water will be slower.That's not really a problem, unless you invite many people and they all want to take a shower at the same time and empty the water heater.

I've cleaned up a few that were full of scale. On wall mounted vertical tanks, there's a small hatch on the bottom. Cut the power, remove the screws or bolts, open it, put a bucket below, stick your arm in the hole, and you'll pull out a surprisingly large amount of scale.

On other models of tanks, the hatch may be on the side, which makes it much more complicated to get the scale out.

Obviously you should turn off the water inlet valve and empty the tank first, then either wait for it to cool or fill it again halfway with cold water and empty it again. Otherwise you'll burn yourself.

It's not difficult. You will need a spare joint though. It's not always necessary to change it but it's better to have it in case the joint gets damaged during the process, otherwise you will have cold showers while waiting for a new one.

> So I'm thinking to just let it go until it stops working and rather just replace it with a new.

When a water heater dies, usually it's the thermostat or the heating element, both can be replaced at lower cost (also much quicker and easier to do). If the tank leaks then the whole heater needs replacing.